# DOORS creates Object ID while they are not saved

Tags: requirements, configuration-management, ibm-doors

I am adding some 2000 new objects to a DOORS module, I do this by importing a spread sheet with blank IDs, DOORS is supposed to create IDs for those blank rows.
Now the problem is, while i import spreadsheet, DOORS hangs, then when i Kill DOORS process, it anyhow creates IDs, next time when i add a new object, ID number starts from those which are already created but no exist. For some reason i need to continue from my last saved ID. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

several remarks here:

- works as designed. As soon as an object is created in any DOORS session, the new absolute number is centrally marked as "used". I think the main reason for this feature is the possibility to work in shared mode. If there were a different design, you would get into trouble as soon as two developers work on the module at the same time.
- are you sure that DOORS really hangs? Perhaps it is just not yet finished, at least you can see that the objects are really created. Note that depending on how the script is written that you use for import, the number of imports per second might decrease significantly for bigger files
- You should NEVER give any meaning to the absolute number other than uniqueness (perhaps QSS should have used timestamps or UUIDS instead of integers for their absolute numbers when they designed DOORS, this would make the situation clearer). You will have to rework “some reasons” . Perhaps you use a different mechanism to assign your own ID mechanism or you have to evaluate whether the requirement “generate consecutive numbers without gaps” is really necessary.

Comment: ,Your remarks answer some of the questions I had. With respect your first remark, the module wasn't opened in shareable edit mode. I feel that though I've create an object, as long as it not saved I should be able to re-use it.

Comment: Well, I can only guess. It seems like DOORS uses the same mechanism to get a new Absolute Number regardless of the mode that the user used to open the module, i.e. “request a new absolute number from the server while marking it as being used”. One might have invented different methods for different open modes, but I imagine that this way it was safer to implement. And with regards to the 3rd remark it makes no difference. Disregarding this 3rd remark is one of the most common errors when designing a data model for DOORS, as it's so easy to overlook.